# ¿ Cómo crear un trigger en sqlServer para descontar el stock?

Tags: sql-server-2012

Tengo este trigger que funciona en [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql). Obviamente al copiar y pegar en sqlServer 2012 me tira errores.
necesito que funcione en sqlServer 2012.
Este es el trigger de mySql:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_subtractBookStock
AFTER INSERT ON detalleventas
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE libros
SET cantidad = cantidad - new.Cantidad
WHERE IdLibro = new.IdLibro;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La principal diferencia, además de las puramente sintácticas, entre los *triggers* de SQL Server y los de otros motores, es que en SQL Server

- No se lanzan los *triggers* para cada fila (no hay equivalente a `for each row`).
- Por la misma zacón, no existen los pseudo-registros `old` y `new` del estándar (y que implementan muchos motores)<sup>1</sup>.

En SQL Server, lo que existe son las pseudo-tablas `inserted` y `deleted`, que tienen la misma estructura de campos que la tabla sub-yacente. Como cae de su peso, en `inserted` están siempre los datos que se están insertando y en `deleted` los datos que se están eliminando.

Además, cuando el trigger se lanza a raíz de una sentencia `update`, la pseudo tabla `deleted` tiene los valores anteriores en la tabla y la pseudo tabla `inserted` los nuevos valores. Es decir, son más o menos equivalentes a `old` y `new`.

Tomando en cuenta estos cambios, un trigger que haga la misma función en SQL Server sería más o menos como este:

```
create trigger tr_subtractBookStock
    on detalleventas
 after insert
as 
begin
  with TotalesPorLibro as (
    select idLibro, sum(Cantidad) TotalCantidad
      from Inserted
     group by idLibro
    having sum(Cantidad) != 0
  )
  update Libros
     set cantidad = cantidad - TotalesPorLibro.TotalCantidad
    from Libros
         inner join TotalesPorLibro on TotalesPorLibro.idLibro = Libros.IdLibro
END
```

Como se puede observar, me he dado primero a la tarea de *resumir* las cantidades por idLIbro en el *CTE* TotalesPorLibro, ya que la sentencia `update/from` no soporta actualizar varias veces la misma fila, es una precaución que suelo tomar en caso que se incluya varias filas para el mismo libro en un `insert`.

Otra diferencia importante es que trato los datos en su conjunto. Esto puede no parecer importante al inicio y, de hecho, lo más común es que las inserciones ocurran una a una. Sin embargo, realizar el tratamiento de esta manera puede significar una diferencia importante en el desempeño del motor, que está especializado en realizar este tipo de operaciones de manera bastante eficiente y que superan, por mucho, a los enfoques que van fila por fila tratando los datos.

---

<sup>1</sup>: Esa es la razón por la que estoy escribiendo una respuesta a la pregunta, no por la simple traducción de un dialecto de SQL a otro.

Comment: Gracias @jachguate por la data y el trigger funciona perfecto!